# Filter Stream, ‘track’ works but ‘locations’ doesnt

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

New guy, I've been hunting for hours for an answer on this but no luck so far so here I am.

I'm following [Mike Pultz's Streaming Example here](http://mikepultz.com/2013/06/mining-twitter-api-v1-1-streams-from-php-with-oauth/) in attempt to get a 'locations' stream working. Theoretically, I should just be able to change 'track' for 'locations' on line 64 or so when he's building the $data variable to be inserted in the request right? Then on the front end I would need to insert the two lng/lat pairs instead of my track keywords.

I can get the stream to work with the 'track' filter on but as soon as I switch to 'locations' I get a 401 error. Any ideas?

I'll paste my code here (minus keys)

ctwitter_stream.php

```
    <?php
class ctwitter_stream
{
    private $m_oauth_consumer_key;
    private $m_oauth_consumer_secret;
    private $m_oauth_token;
    private $m_oauth_token_secret;

    private $m_oauth_nonce;
    private $m_oauth_signature;
    private $m_oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    private $m_oauth_timestamp;
    private $m_oauth_version = '1.0';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
        // set a time limit to unlimited
        //
        set_time_limit(0);
    }

    //
    // set the login details
    //
    public function login($_consumer_key, $_consumer_secret, $_token, $_token_secret)
    {
        $this->m_oauth_consumer_key     = $_consumer_key;
        $this->m_oauth_consumer_secret  = $_consumer_secret;
        $this->m_oauth_token            = $_token;
        $this->m_oauth_token_secret     = $_token_secret;

        //
        // generate a nonce; we're just using a random md5() hash here.
        //
        $this->m_oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());

        return true;
    }

    //
    // process a tweet object from the stream
    //
    private function process_tweet($_data)
    {
        print_r($_data['text']);
        print("<br /><br />");

        return true;
    }

    //
    // the main stream manager
    //
    public function start($_keywords)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            $fp = fsockopen("ssl://stream.twitter.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if (!$fp)
            {
                echo "ERROR: Twitter Stream Error: failed to open socket";
            } else
            {
                //
                // build the data and store it so we can get a length
                //
                $data = 'track=' . rawurlencode(implode($_keywords, ','));

                //
                // store the current timestamp
                //
                $this->m_oauth_timestamp = time();

                //
                // generate the base string based on all the data
                //
                $base_string = 'POST&' . 
                    rawurlencode('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json') . '&' .
                    rawurlencode('oauth_consumer_key=' . $this->m_oauth_consumer_key . '&' .
                        'oauth_nonce=' . $this->m_oauth_nonce . '&' .
                        'oauth_signature_method=' . $this->m_oauth_signature_method . '&' . 
                        'oauth_timestamp=' . $this->m_oauth_timestamp . '&' .
                        'oauth_token=' . $this->m_oauth_token . '&' .
                        'oauth_version=' . $this->m_oauth_version . '&' .
                        $data);

                //
                // generate the secret key to use to hash
                //
                $secret = rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_consumer_secret) . '&' . 
                    rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_token_secret);

                //
                // generate the signature using HMAC-SHA1
                //
                // hash_hmac() requires PHP >= 5.1.2 or PECL hash >= 1.1
                //
                $raw_hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $secret, true);

                //
                // base64 then urlencode the raw hash
                //
                $this->m_oauth_signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode($raw_hash));

                //
                // build the OAuth Authorization header
                //
                $oauth = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' . $this->m_oauth_consumer_key . '", ' .
                        'oauth_nonce="' . $this->m_oauth_nonce . '", ' .
                        'oauth_signature="' . $this->m_oauth_signature . '", ' .
                        'oauth_signature_method="' . $this->m_oauth_signature_method . '", ' .
                        'oauth_timestamp="' . $this->m_oauth_timestamp . '", ' .
                        'oauth_token="' . $this->m_oauth_token . '", ' .
                        'oauth_version="' . $this->m_oauth_version . '"';

                //
                // build the request
                //
                $request  = "POST /1.1/statuses/filter.json HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                $request .= "Host: stream.twitter.com\r\n";
                $request .= "Authorization: " . $oauth . "\r\n";
                $request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";
                $request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
                $request .= $data;
                print $request;
                print '<br />';

                //
                // write the request
                //
                fwrite($fp, $request);

                //
                // set it to non-blocking
                //
                stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

                while(!feof($fp))
                {
                    $read   = array($fp);
                    $write  = null;
                    $except = null;

                    //
                    // select, waiting up to 10 minutes for a tweet; if we don't get one, then
                    // then reconnect, because it's possible something went wrong.
                    //
                    $res = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 600, 0);
                    if ( ($res == false) || ($res == 0) )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    //
                    // read the JSON object from the socket
                    //
                    $json = fgets($fp);

                    //
                    // look for a HTTP response code
                    //
                    if (strncmp($json, 'HTTP/1.1', 8) == 0)
                    {
                        $json = trim($json);
                        if ($json != 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
                        {
                            echo 'ERROR: ' . $json . "\n";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    //
                    // if there is some data, then process it
                    //
                    if ( ($json !== false) && (strlen($json) > 0) )
                    {
                        //
                        // decode the socket to a PHP array
                        //
                        $data = json_decode($json, true);
                        if ($data)
                        {
                            //
                            // process it
                            //
                            $this->process_tweet($data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fclose($fp);
            sleep(10);
        }

        return;
    }
};
?>
```

twitter_front.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php
 require 'ctwitter_stream.php';
 ?>
</head>

<body>
test

<?php 
$t = new ctwitter_stream();
$t->login("key", "secret", "token", "");
$t->start(array('albuquerque','abq','burque','land of enchantment'));
// $t->start(array('-106.77','35.00','-106.43','35.25'));
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Edited: tag